# Socket.io, why does it need an http server?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

Looking at the following example from the Socket.IO lib (or any other example):

```
// note, io(<port>) will create a http server for you
var io = require('socket.io')(80);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  io.emit('this', { will: 'be received by everyone'});

  socket.on('private message', function (from, msg) {
    console.log('I received a private message by ', from, ' saying ', msg);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    io.emit('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

It seems that Socket.IO is always dependent on a http server, to the point that it will create one for you, like in the example above.

Since websockets are not HTTP, why are http servers needed? If it is only for fallbacks, why is it so thoughly integrated?

Comment: Websocket is created when you make upgrade from http to websocket, so it kind of *does* need http.

Comment: @Azamantes . Please explain the same in detail. Even I want to know more about it. It'd be great to see the answer to this. Thanks

Comment: @Azamantes, AFAIK if you use a browser's WebSocket api, there is not need for an http server

Comment: `socket.io` isn't a pure Websocket server/implementation, it depends on HTTP for its initial connection setup.

Comment: @omerts yeah you have that browser's WebSocket API and what are you going to connect it to? You have a client and a server, something is going to receive your request and upgrade the connection from http to websocket protocol

Comment: @Azamantes Correct me if I am wrong, but from what I understood "Its only relationship to HTTP is that its handshake is interpreted by HTTP servers as an Upgrade request", doesn't mean an http-server is required, only if one exists how it reacts. The handshake message also have a similar to http req/res, so you are able to handle both http & websocket on the same port. You could establish websocket communication without an http server.

Comment: @omerts "Once a connection to the server has been established (including a connection via a proxy or over a TLS-encrypted tunnel), the client MUST send an opening handshake to the server. The handshake consists of an HTTP Upgrade request, along with a list of required and optional header fields.", see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-1.4 page 17

Comment: The [`ws`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) package is for you. It creates a plain `WebSocket` server, without a fully-functional HTTP server.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Since websockets are not HTTP, why are http servers needed?

The premise on which your question seems to be based is that `socket.io` is a websocket library, which it isn't.

It's a real time, bidirectional event-based communication library (blurb from homepage). One of the transports that it uses are websockets, but it also provides other transports (XHR/JSONP), not *just* as a fallback but also for situations where websockets aren't supported/required/wanted.

On top of the transport, it offers additional functionality like segmentation (namespaces, rooms), acknowledgements, broadcasts, etc.

Even when websockets can be used, the initial connection setup it done over HTTP. Also, a `socket.io` server will attach to an HTTP server so it can serve its own client code through `/socket.io/socket.io.js`.

That said, although you don't *need* an HTTP server to regular websockets, there's no denying that the websocket protocol was designed with HTTP in mind (as to allow HTTP and websocket servers to co-exist on the same TCP port).

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)